# Getting different formats of numbers from string using regex

Tags: regex

I need to get these number formats from a string

```
20000
20 000
20 000 000
20 000,00
20 000.00
2000,000
200000.000
```

Strings can be

```
some text 20000
20000 some text
```

So far I have this

```
/((\d){1,}[ .,]{1}[0-9]{1,}[ .,]{1}[0-9]{1,})/g
```

Thank you.

Comment: Explain the number `2000,000` and what this means.

Comment: In `2000,000` (not `2,000,000`) does the comma translate as a period in English?

Comment: Yes, it is a period in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this regex:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:[ ,]?\d{3})*(?:[,.]\d+)?$
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
^                from the start of the string
[1-9][0-9]{0,2}  match 1 to 3 leading digits (first digit not zero)
(?:[ ,]?\d{3})*  then match an optional thousands separator followed by 3 digits,
                 the entire quantity zero or more times
(?:[,.]\d+)?     match an optional decimal component, using either , or . as the separator
$                end of the string
```

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen  How can I use it on string like this 20 000 some text. Looks like it matches only numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Replace the `^` and `$` anchors with word boundaries, i.e. use `\b[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:[ ,]?\d{3})*(?:[,.]\d+)?\b`

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen Thank you very much.